# How to access VirtualBox running on OSX over RDP

Tags: virtualbox

So, I read the manual three times, installed the Oracle service pack two times, tried to access five different virtual machines dozens of times with all kinds of authentications, followed every thread on this forum, all to no avail. I really did everything there is to do to my knowledge. But accessing Virtualbox regardless of the OS does not work in version 4.1.23. Two things seem just really bad:

1. The manual tells at no point WHERE on OSX the VBoxManager commandline tool is installed. But the manual references it dozens of times. It's on no search path in none of the shells I am using. Doing a find / -name "VBoxManager" as root reveals there is no such tool anywhere. Please, can someone let me know what to do to actually be able to do what the manual says with regard to the command line? Where does one get that tool?
2. I still would like to learn how one accesses a virtualbox installation with a remote screen. Here is what I tried;
   as clients:
3. Apple Remote Desktop
   Fails to find server
4. Apple VNC protocol from Finder
   Fails to find server
5. VNCViewer (even though that is as unlikely to work for RDP as option 2)
   Fails to find server
6. Microsoft Remotedesktop (that should work).
   Fails to authenticate, after hitting the connect button one gets instantly the response that authentication failed, regardless of

   - means of authentication, such as NULL, External
   - Network interface (bridged, NAT)
   - IP address (the one the virtual machine obtains, localhost, my own host's ip address)
   - Port (tried different ports none of which were occupied)
   - Virtual OS (Windows 7, Windows XP, CentOS 6.3, ClearOS, backtrack 5)

Please, can someone help?